# Vercel is deploying the wrong commit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, google-cloud-firestore, vercel

I have a project that I just tried to deploy with vercel, it was a code test from a potential employer and the code was full of errors and bugs at first.. I slowly fixed all the errors vercel gave me on build and it finally compiled and deployed.. HOWEVER vercel has deployed the base project that was sent to me whereas when I run npm start locally I see the completed project I did.

Any insight would be much appreciated on why vercel would deploy the wrong commit.

Comment: Are you using the Vercel CLI to deploy your project? If so, you need to run `vercel --prod` to deploy your code to production.

Comment: I've deployed another project with vercel previously where I just simply imported it straight from github and vercel handled the building and deploying; I've done the exact same for this project however when it deploys with vercel it's the version of the app that I first commit rather than the current commit I get when running it locally.

Comment: If you imported the project from github, then all you need to do is `git push` to deploy. Each PR will get its own URL and then merging to the main branch will deploy to Production. Take a look at https://vercel.com/docs/git/vercel-for-github

Answer (score -3):

Just click the home page of your app (click your vercel name) and vercel will deploy the latest commit.

Comment: I tried it again many times and it is working. It is always working for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The click on name causes the server to reload all your project. In the process your latest commit is will be deployed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31835989)

Comment: check if your commit is showing some error